# SPI communication not working during Run time?

Tags: spi, dac, 8051, texas-instruments

For my project i need to communicate between Microcontroller C8051f350 [Datasheet](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F35x.pdf) (Silab Microcontroller) and TI DAC116s997 [DataSheet](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/snas621a/snas621a.pdf) IC through SPI.

The problem i am facing a problem in SPI communication. SPI communication works fine when debbugging (single step). But when i run programme without break points SPI communication fails.

Here is Code for communication,
SPI Initialisation

```
//! @brief Initialise the SPI
// SPI mode - 0, CPOL=0 CPHA=0
// SPI0CN = 1, ENABLE SPI
// fSCK =SYSCLK/2*(SPI0CKR+1)
// SYSCLK = 24.5Mhz SPI0CKR = 9, SPI FRQ(fSCK) = 1.2Mhz
#define Init_SPI()  {                                               \
    SPI0CFG   = 0x40;                                                   \
    SPI0CN    = 0x01;                                                   \
    SPI0CKR   = 9;                                                  \
}
```

Initialisation process for DAC

```
MT_SPI_Write(8, 0xC33C);        // RESET the DAC
MT_SPI_Write(2, 0);             // Followed by NOP command after reset
```

Continously write DAC value in 1ms Timer ISR

```
/**
 * @brief   1ms Timer ISR for timer 3
 * @author  Sushant
 * @param   None
 * @return  None.
 */
void ISR_Timer3()   interrupt 14
{
    Word lwRes;
    CLEAR_TIMER3_FLAG();
                //  DACCODE ADDRESS, DAC VALUE
    lwRes = MT_SPI_Write(4,          32767);
    MT_SPI_Write(0x89, 0);      // read status register

}
```

SPI Functions:

```
/**
 * @brief   This function writes 24 bits on DAC through SPI
 * @param   lbAdd - Address of DAC register
 * @param   lwData - Data to be written at address specified
 * @return  16 bit data received from DAC in return
 */
Word MT_SPI_Write(Byte lbAdd, Word lwData)
{
    UN_Word lunResult;
    UN_Word lunData;
    lunData.W = lwData;
    DAC_CS = 0;                                 // CS = 0
    Send_SPI(lbAdd);                            // Address of register
    lunResult.B[0] = Send_SPI(lunData.B[0]);    // Higher byte of register
    lunResult.B[1] = Send_SPI(lunData.B[1]);    // Lower byte of register
    DAC_CS = 1;                                 // CS = 1

    return lunResult.W;
}
Byte Send_SPI(Byte lbData)
{

    while(!TXBMT);          // Wait if transmit buffer is not empty

    SPI0DAT = lbData;       // Write the data in SPI Tx buffer

    while(!SPIF);           // Wait till transfer is complete

    SPIF=0;                 // Clear the transfer complete flag

    lbData = SPI0DAT;       // read the data from SPI Rx buffer

    return (lbData);        // Returns the data
 }
```

Comment: Wait... You are calling a Polling based function (`Send_SPI`) in an ISR. Not a good practise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem has been solved, it was somewhere timing error as mentioned above by Some Hardware Guy.
Even though DAC116s997 working frequency is in Mhz. DAC was not responding till i lowered frequency to 400kHz.

At 400Khz or lower frequency SPI communication is established and DAC is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a timing of events problem.   When you do that back to back spi write command are you waiting for the first one to complete?   If not when you single step the hardware probably has time to write the data out the serial bus before you write the spi register again.

You could lazily try a delay loop between the two, but a better approach would be to check the spi status bits to see when the hardware is ready for the next write.

Comment: I Ve modified Q and Added SPI functions. i doubt there is any programming bug in SPI routines.